# What is the incentive for miners to include uncle headers of other miners?

Tags: mining

Since EIP100 includes uncles into difficulty calculation. As such, why would a miner include uncles other than their own?

Answer (score 0):

The miner gets an extra 1/32 of the block reward extra for each uncle they include. From the "Yellow paper" section 11.3 Reward application.